# How to install job dependent libraries and .whl package on Databricks Job cluster

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-databricks, databricks-workflows

We have the .whl package(customised module) that needs to be installed on the Databricks job cluster the moment when the new job cluster spins-up for ADF jobs. Let me know how we can push the .whl package to the newly spined-up cluster.

Any pointers would help.

Answer (score 3):

When creating pipeline in Azure Data Factory, and [adding Databricks activity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-databricks-notebook#create-a-pipeline), click onto "Settings", expand item "Append libraries", and click "New". Then select `wheel` as library type, and specify path to the library on DBFS (it should be uploaded there).

[image]

Comment: Does this install the library in the job cluster when it boots up? If yes, how does the time compare to downloading from PyPI and installing (using init scripts). If no, how is the Python Library made available to the notebook?

Comment: Alex, do you know if it's possible to attach a library from a Unity Catalog Volume?

Comment: Should be possible, but I didn't test